# implementing focal loss on large CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, keras-2

I have an image binary classification problem, with only 15% of the data from class 1, and 85% of it is from class 0.

I decided to work with focal loss to deal with the unbalanced dataset and noticed something. When I use a fairly simple cnn, I see the focal loss working, managing to classify more than just one class (with accuracy more than 85%).

The thing is, when I switch the cnn to be a 50 layer resnet, it doesn't work. It classifies every photo with class 0, keeping the accuracy locked at 85% with AUC of 0.5. Why is this happening?
The images are 180x180x3.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you don't use focal loss? How can you be sure that this is caused by it?

Comment: it's the same when using binaryCrossEntropy...

Comment: Then it's clearly not a focal loss problem. You might want to change your title. But then it becomes a really generic question that is hard to solve with many possible causes. I would suggest 1. decreasing learning rate (by a factor of 10 or even 100) 2. test your resnet on some other tasks.

Comment: Only found out later that BCE does the same thing. Thanks for the advice. I will say that the resnet i'm using is the default 50 layer one, and that I used it with the focal loss on some other task and it worked. But I can see what you mean by generic. Thanks